# Not receiving full data in client Winsock

Tags: c++, serialization, winsock

I have a problem in winsock client-server when sending the data. I have a map containing a username as Primary Key, and a vector of messages for each user (stored in structs):
`map<std::string,std::vector<message *> > data;`

```
struct message{
        static unsigned int last_id;
        unsigned int id;
        std::string baa;
        std::string timestamp;
    }
```

I also have a serializer in order to send it to the client via Winsock (that only accepts arrays of chars)

```
class MessageSerializer
{
public:
    MessageSerializer(const message& messageStruct)
    : m_msgRef(messageStruct)
    , m_msgLength(m_msgRef.msg.length())
    , m_timeLength(m_msgRef.timestamp.length())
    {}

    size_t RequiredBufferSize() const
    {
        return sizeof(int) + sizeof(size_t)*2 + m_msgLength + m_timeLength;
    }

    void Serialize(void* buffer) const
    {
        PushNum     (buffer, m_msgRef.id);
        PushString  (buffer, m_msgRef.msg.c_str(), m_msgLength);
        PushString  (buffer, m_msgRef.timestamp.c_str(), m_timeLength);
    }
private:
    const message&  m_msgRef;
    const size_t    m_msgLength;
    const size_t    m_timeLength;

    template<typename INTEGER>
    void PushNum(void*& buffer, INTEGER num) const
    {
        INTEGER* ptr = static_cast<INTEGER*>(buffer);
        //copying content
        *ptr = num;
        //updating the buffer pointer to point the next position to copy
        buffer = ++ptr;
    }
    void PushString(void*& buffer, const char* cstr, size_t length) const
    {
        PushNum(buffer, length);
        //copying string content
        memcpy(buffer, cstr, length);
        //updating the buffer pointer to point the next position to copy
        char* ptr = static_cast<char*>(buffer);
        ptr += length;
        buffer = ptr;
    }
}
```

And to implement this serializer, I make the following:

```
message msg_cpy=*data[recvbuf_usrn].at(0);
MessageSerializer serializer(msg_cpy);
char* buffer = new char[serializer.RequiredBufferSize()];
serializer.Serialize(buffer);
```

The problem comes when sending the timestamp. In `msg_cpy` I have the data correctly stored(e.g. id=1, msg=hello, timestamp=2016-04-02 10:40:45), but when sending the data, the timestamp only saves the first three values, that is to say, in the client, I receive after deserializing id=1, msg=hello, and timestamp=201 followed by trash. I know the problem resides in the server, and I deduce it can be the serializing function (the only other alternative could be the "send" function of Winsock). But what could be wrong in it? If I write a msg=2016-04-02 10:40:20, I receive that in the client.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should try to build a [mcve]. The problem could lie in the way you use the serializer to send the data, that is in code not shown (and my crystal ball is currently out of use...)

Comment: To send data I send the `buffer` returning from `serializer.Serialize(buffer)`, as the Winsock function to send only allows array of chars. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx) In this webpage appears the send function of Winsock, that takes `recvbuf` as input data, which, in my case, is the buffer. But I think the problem resides when serializing, where buffer takes already the trash in the timestamp part. That's why I did not attach the rest. If you could have any idea why it happens I'd appreciate it much. Thanks anyway! @serge-ballesta

Comment: This is just a wild hunch since you didn't include the send/receive code: TCP is a stream-oriented protocol; a single `recv()` may not return all of the data. You need to loop calling `recv()` until a complete "message" is received.

Comment: Yoy are right @keithmo I thought the problem was at serializing, and it was in the buffer length I was entering in the send function of the server, that was always smaller than the needed one. The serializer was working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you showed is correct. The error is is the code you do not show.

With the 2 classes `message` and `MessageSerializer`, I tried that simple test:

```
int main() {
    message msg = {1, "foo", "2016-04-02 10:40:20" };

    MessageSerializer msgSer(msg);

    size_t sz = msgSer.RequiredBufferSize();
    char * buffer = new char[sz];
    msgSer.Serialize(static_cast<void *>(buffer));
    for (int i=0; i<sz; i++) {
        std::cout << buffer[i] << " (" << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(buffer[i]) << ") ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    delete[] buffer;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is as expected

```
 (1)  (0)  (0)  (0)  (3)  (0)  (0)  (0) f (66) o (6f) o (6f)  (13)  (0)  (0)  (0) 2 (32) 0 (30) 1 (31) 6 (36) - (2d) 0 (30) 4 (34) - (2d) 0 (30) 2 (32)   (20) 1 (31) 0 (30) : (3a) 4 (34) 0 (30) : (3a) 2 (32) 0 (30)
```

Comment: You are right. The problem was in the buffer length I was setting in the winsock send function. The serializer was working good.